# NoSuchMethodError while querying hbase using hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am getting this error when trying to query hbase table using hive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.ColumnProjectionUtils.getReadColumnIDs(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)Ljava/util/ArrayList;
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveHBaseTableInputFormat.java:94)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:471)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:561)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:534)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:137)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1519)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:285)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:423)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:792)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:686)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

I am using Hive 0.13.1, Hadoop 2.4.1, Hbase 0.98.5.

I created a table using the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE hlogcount(rowkey STRING, date DATE, time STRING, logtype STRING, type STRING, value INT) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('hbase.columns.mapping' = ':key,f:c1,f:c2,f:c3,f:c4,f:c5') TBLPROPERTIES ('hbase.table.name' = 'hlogcount');
```

The table was created successfully and can be seen in the output of `show tables;`

the hive lib already has a hive-serde-0.13.1.jar and I have also tried using hive-serde-0.10.0 but it also has the same result.

Comment: Missing/wrong lib in jar?

Comment: no its the original one bundled with the tarball

Comment: It seems there might be missing libraries or having old hbase version libraries in it. Check once or replace the lib folder with new one.